# Ways to speed up SciPy's odeint?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, odeint

I'm calling a function that uses `odeint` at every pass through a for loop (I can't break anything out of that loop, sadly). But, things are running much slower than I'd hoped. Here's the code:

```
def get_STM(t_i, t_f, X_ref_i, dxdt, Amat):
    """Evaluate the state transition matrix rate of change for a given A matrix.
    """

    STM_i = np.eye(X_ref_i.size).flatten()
    args = (dxdt, Amat)
    X_aug_i = np.hstack((X_ref_i, STM_i))
    t = [t_i, t_f]

    # Propogate reference trajectory & STM together!    
    X_aug_f = odeint(dxdt_interface, X_aug_i, t, args=args)
    X_f = X_aug_f[-1, :X_ref_i.size]
    STM_f = X_aug_f[-1, X_ref_i.size:].reshape(X_ref_i.size, X_ref_i.size)

    return X_f, STM_f

def dxdt_interface(X,t,dxdt,Amat):
    """
    Provides an interface between odeint and dxdt
    Parameters :
    ------------
    X : (42-by-1 np array) augmented state (with Phi)
    t : time
    dxdt : (function handle) time derivative of the (6-by-1) state vector
    Amat : (function handle) state-space matrix
    Returns:
    --------
    (42-by-1 np.array) time derivative of the components of the augmented state 
    """
    # State derivative
    Xdot = np.zeros_like(X)
    X_stacked = np.hstack((X[:6], t))
    Xdot_state = dxdt(*(X_stacked))
    Xdot[:6] = Xdot_state[:6].T

    # STM
    Phi = X[6:].reshape((Xdot_state.size, Xdot_state.size))

    # State-Space matrix
    A = Amat(*(X_stacked))
    Xdot[6:] = (A .dot (Phi)).reshape((A.size))

    return Xdot
```

Problem is, I'm calling `get_STM` something on the order of 8640 times per run, and this leads to 232217 calls of `dxdt_interface`, about 70% of my total compute time at 5ms per call of `get_STM` (99.9% of which is due to `odeint`).

I'm new to SciPy's integration techniques, and I can't figure out how to speed this up at all based on `odeint`'s [documentation](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html). I looked into jitting `dxdt_interface` with [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), but I can't get that to work because `dxdt` and `Amat` are symbolic.

Are there any techniques to speed up `odeint` that I'm missing?

EDIT: Included `Amat` and `dxdt` functions below. Note that these aren't called within my major for loop, they create handles to symbolic lambdified functions that are passed to my `get_STM` function (I call `import sympy as sym`).

```
def get_A(use_j3=False):
    """ Returns the jacobian of the state time rate of change
    Parameters
    ----------
    R : Earth's equatorial radius (m)
    theta_dot : Earth's rotation rate (rad/s)
    mu : Earth's standard gravitationnal parameter (m^3/s^2)
    j2 : second zonal harmonic coefficient
    j3 : third zonal harmonic coefficient
    Returns
    ----------    
    A : (function handle) jacobian of the state time rate of change
    """
    theta_dot = EARTH['rotation rate']
    R = EARTH['radius']
    mu = EARTH['mu']
    j2 = EARTH['J2']
    if use_j3:
        j3 = EARTH['J3']
    else:
        j3 = 0

    # Symbolic derivations
    x, y, z, mus, j2s, j3s, Rs, t = sym.symbols('x y z mus j2s j3s Rs t', real=True)
    theta_dots = sym.symbols('theta_dots', real=True)
    xdot,ydot,zdot = sym.symbols('xdot ydot zdot ', real=True)

    X = sym.Matrix([x,y,z,xdot,ydot,zdot])

    A_mat = sym.lambdify( (x,y,z,xdot,ydot,zdot,t), dxdt_s().jacobian(X).subs([
        (theta_dots, theta_dot),(Rs, R),(j2s,j2),(j3s,j3),(mus,mu)]), modules='numpy')

    return A_mat

def Dxdt(use_j3=False):
    """ Returns the time derivative of the state vector
    Parameters
    ----------
    R : Earth's equatorial radius (m)
    theta_dot : Earth's rotation rate (rad/s)
    mu : Earth's standard gravitationnal parameter (m^3/s^2)
    j2 : second zonal harmonic coefficient
    j3 : third zonal harmonic coefficient
    Returns
    ----------    
    dxdt : (function handle) time derivative of the state vector
    """

    theta_dot = EARTH['rotation rate']
    R = EARTH['radius']
    mu = EARTH['mu']
    j2 = EARTH['J2']
    if use_j3:
        j3 = EARTH['J3']
    else:
        j3 = 0

    # Symbolic derivations
    x, y, z, mus, j2s, j3s, Rs, t = sym.symbols('x y z mus j2s j3s Rs t', real=True)
    theta_dots = sym.symbols('theta_dots', real=True)
    xdot,ydot,zdot = sym.symbols('xdot ydot zdot ', real=True)

    dxdt = sym.lambdify( (x,y,z,xdot,ydot,zdot,t), dxdt_s().subs([
        (theta_dots, theta_dot),(Rs, R),(j2s,j2),(j3s,j3),(mus,mu)]), modules='numpy')

    return dxdt
```

Comment: I think you need to speedup  dxdt and Amat. Maybe use codegen in sympy to generate C or Fortran code and create the dxdt_interface with cython.

Answer (score 0):

With `dxdt` and `Amat` as black boxes, there isn't a lot that you can do to speed this up.  One possibility is to streamline calling them.  The `hstack` might be overkill.

```
In [355]: def dxdt_quiet(*args):
    x=args
    return x
   .....: 
In [356]: t=1.23
In [357]: dxdt_quiet(*xs)
Out[357]: (0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 1.23)
In [358]: dxdt_quiet(*tuple(x[:6])+(t,))
Out[358]: (0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 1.23)
```

the tuple approach is quite a bit faster:

```
In [359]: timeit dxdt_quiet(*tuple(x[:6])+(t,))
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.1 µs per loop
In [360]: %%timeit
xs=np.hstack((x[:6],1.234))
dxdt_quiet(*xs)
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.4 µs per loop
```

I'd do more testing like this to optimize the `dxdt_interface` calls.

Comment: Just edited my post to include `dxdt` and `Amat` creation functions. I also replaced the `hstack` call with the following: `X_stacked = tuple(list(X[:6]) + [t])`, but didn't notice any significant speedup.